# Embed HTML + javascript files in Visual Studio Winforms Project

Tags: html, visual-studio, browser

I'm having a hard time trying to integrate some things I thought they would be easy to integrate, but I was wrong.

I have an html file and some javascript files (with no server logic in the html code) and i need to embed them in a Visual Studio winform Project in order to use a WebBrowser control an invoke this html file (which includes the .js files) and I need to have the files inside the client application when I call them.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is in one file, you can embed the file in a ResX container and write

```
webBrowser.DocumentText = Resources.HtmlSource;
```

If you have multiple files (eg, images and external `.js` files), you'll need to copy them to physical files on the end-user's machine to make relative paths work.  (or you could put them all into a `.mhtml` file)